# $chsh command security with Set-UID

Tags: linux

Why does $chsh have to be a Set-UID command? What are the vulnerabilities of a normal user changing his/her own shell from perhaps bash to zsh?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no `$` within the name of this command on any Unix. Its correct name is: `chsh` or `/usr/bin/chsh`.

Answer (score 3):

`chsh` is setuid because in order to change a user's shell, it must modify the root-owned read-only `/etc/passwd` file.

The system administrator may wish to limit which shells a user may choose, for example if users are assigned a shell which logs all commands to syslog.  The traditional way to do this would be to remove all other shells from the `/etc/shells` file, as `chsh` restricts users to choosing shells in that file.  (That then implies that for any users who aren't restricted in that manner, an administrator needs to change their shells by hand - editing `/etc/passwd` - since they can no longer use chsh to do it.)

Comment: Should a system admin. restrict normal users from changing their own shells? If so, what security concerns may arise if normal users are able to change their shells?

Answer (score 2):

There is no vulnerability for a normal user to change their shell.

However, a user's shell is stored in the user database, together with other sensitive fields. Most Unix variants store the database of local users in a single file, `/etc/passwd`. (The name comes from the fact that the original Unix stored users' passwords in that file; on modern systems, passwords are no longer stored in `/etc/passwd`, which is world-readable, but in a file that isn't world-readable, such as `/etc/shadow` on Solaris and Linux.) While allowing a normal user to change their shell isn't a security concern, some other fields are sensitive (e.g. the user ID) — but mostly, the file contains information about all users, so allowing a user to modify it would be disastrous since they could change anybody else's account.

Thus users can only modify `/etc/passwd` indirectly, through commands such as `chsh` and `chfn`.

Furthermore, it would be a vulnerability to allow restricted users to change their shells. An account can be restricted to run a specific command by setting that specific command nothing as their shell (or even or effectively prevented from logging in altogether by setting `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` — or `/bin/true` for that matter — as the shell). If the user was somehow able to change their login shell, they would evade the account restriction. The restriction is implemented in `chsh` by refusing to change the shell if the user's current shell is not in a whitelist of permitted “generalist” shells stored in `/etc/shells`.

Additionally, the `chsh` command refuses to change a user's shell *to* a shell that isn't in this whitelist. This ensures that users won't lock themselves out of their account by setting a bad shell there, which isn't a security concern but is a support concern.

To summarize, `chsh` has to have elevated privileges because it needs to modify a file that's shared among all users. This allows `chsh` to apply additional useful policies.

While it would be possible to split out the shell into a separate per-user file, that would require a more complex design with one separate file per account. Unix was based on simple designs, with information stored on flat text file. Fine-grained access control with one datum per file is not traditional, would have a performance impact (not a big one nowadays though), and the advantages in terms of security (not requiring `chsh` and `chfn` to have elevated privileges) are pretty small. So there's no compelling reason to change this design.

While it would be possible and relatively simple to make `/etc/passwd` owned by a dedicated system account (or better, a group), and make `chsh` setuid (or better, setgid) to that dedicated account, there wouldn't really be a security benefit. If you manage to exploit `chsh`, never mind what else you can do with `chsh` itself, you're pretty much guaranteed to be able to allow yourself access to the root account.